# How to display the index for multiple elements with same value in an array list

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, while-loop

Can't printout the indexes for all the elements with the same value from an array list. Only the index for the first element found in the array list is printed out.

Current output when list = 5,5,4,5:
Number 5 can be found in the following indexes [0, 0, 0, 0]

The desired output would be:
Number 5 can be found in the following indexes [0, 1, 3]

How I would want the code to work is that the user has to enter integers to an array list until the value -1 is entered. After that system prints out "What number are you looking for?". User enters the number for the element(s) that is wanted to be fetched from the array list. After that system prints out "Number 5 can be found in the following indexes [0, 1, 3].

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sandbox{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            int read = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
            if (read == -1) {
                break;
            }

            list.add(read);
        }
        System.out.print("What number are you looking for? ");
        int requestednumb = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
        int count = 0;

        ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((list.size() > count)) {
            if (list.contains(requestednumb))
                ;
            index.add(list.indexOf(requestednumb));
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number " + requestednumb + " can be found in the following indexes " + index);
    }

}
```

`

I'm pretty sure that it's an silly beginner mistake I have made, but after being stuck with this problem for multiple hours, I hope you can find the time to help me with this.

Comment: When you add a semicolon after a conditional statement, you close the statement without doing anything: `if (list.contains(requestednumb))  ;`  Use braces around the statement after it so the conditional will work.

Comment: .contains returns true/false, but .indexOf returns the first matching index.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see where the 0 is coming from now, thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` loop to change the index and check the number at the given index:

```java
for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
    if (list.get(i) == requestednumb) { // check the number at index i
        index.add(i); // store the index
    }
}
```

---

Or, with `while` loop and `count` used as the index:

```java
int count = 0;

ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
while (count < list.size()) {
    if (list.get(count) == requestednumb) {
        index.add(count);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it. Both solutions work like a charm, but for the final version I decided to use the for loop. Because it's easier for me to understand the mechanics behind it and I can easily modify it to for example printout one row per index found. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
static <T> List<Integer> findIndices(List<T> list, T key) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> list.get(i).equals(key))
        .boxed().toList();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = List.of(5, 5, 4, 5);
    System.out.println(findIndices(list, 5));
}
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 3]
```